# does openbox cause an ubuntu internal error?

Tags: openbox

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I get this error constantly, and i don't know what should i do :(

I use the lubuntu 12.04

does lxde come with openbox, i don't know whether i have installed openbox.

PS.i found when i right-click the gnome-terminal, the screen flashed and the error occurs.

Comment: Lxde uses Openbox as its wm, so yes it does come with Openbox. As for your error I'm at a loss, it seems there is a problem with libc (whick seems unlikely).  Can you pastebin the whole error, some of it is cut off in you screeshots.

Comment: @Spilt_Blood That must have to wait for the next time I cncounter the issue

Comment: @Spilt_Blood I have update the post, see what it useful.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The openbox version (L)ubuntu 12.04 ships with is known to have [issues with crashes](https://bugzilla.icculus.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5460) when using GTK 3 applications. What worked for me was adding [this PPA](https://bugzilla.icculus.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5460) with updated Lubuntu packages.

Please make sure to read through these before adding new PPAs:

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

[Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo?lq=1)

---

If you are ready to proceed you can add the PPA and upgrade your system with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mati75/lubuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

P.S.: You can safe yourself a lot of work if you just copy paste the error log next time. It must have taken you ages to take these screenshots!

Comment: how can i copy paste the error log? where can i find it,pleas let me know

Comment: @haolly I am not 100% sure but I think you should be able to find the error logs under `/var/crash/`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, bug reports are off-topic here, but as Glutanimate said, you should probably use the PPA to fix that crash. But still, in the report says that you have **Obsolete packages** and that's why you can't report the bug.

[image]

You **must** upgrade your system packages and go with Glutanimate solution. If you don't do so, you **will expect more of this error (or others)**. The key to solve bugs is keeping your system update.